# Can't select all value in grid table through admin panel (Magento)

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, grid, magento-1.7

In the admin panel for Magento I'm unable to select all value in grid table in several ways:

when I cliked on "select all" upear to me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectAll' of undefined"

I can select checkbox each one separately but when I clicked on submit upear to me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

[Any thoughts on what might be causing this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUZoz.png)